# String to File removing quotation marks

Tags: files-and-directories

If I print a string to a file it also adds quotation marks to the string. Here is an example:

```
a = "test \t test"
a >> file
FilePrint["file"]
```

How can I remove those? And is it possible to use `\t` for a tabulator?

Comment: see OpenWrite[] and WriteString[]

Comment: Depending on your problem, `Export` offers many formatting options that may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may be looking for is the following

```
a = "test\ntest";
fn = "test";
Put[OutputForm[a], fn];
FilePrint @ fn
```

> ```
> test
> test
> ```

As the documentation for [`Put`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Put.html) states: "Put by default writes expressions in InputForm." So you have to wrap the expression you are writing out with `OutputForm`.

Note: you could rewrite the above code as

```
a = "test\ntest";
OutputForm[a] >> "test"
FilePrint @ "test"
```

but I personally don't use `>>` -- I have a dislike of it because it uses non-standard evaluation.

Also, I should note that I changed `\t` to `\n` only because `\n` makes for a better demonstration effect.